# Wireless Mouse stuttering/mouse recognized as a keyboard - Ubuntu 18.04.1 - Mouse Trust GXT 130 - Lenovo y580

Tags: 18.04, mouse, lenovo

I have a problem with my wireless mouse, from time to time it begin to stutter, it freezes for some ms, making annoying to use it. I've tried many things, some they seem to work, but the problem reappears after a while. I see that the mouse is recognized as a keyboard too, could this be the problem? If that is, how can I change that?

(Mouse wireless Trust GXT 130; laptop lenovo y580 - 8 Gb RAM, Nvidia, 660M, i7; Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS)

```
dmesg | grep Trust
[    2.578966] usb 1-1.2: Product: Trust Gaming Mouse
[    2.580501] input: MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming Mouse as /devices        /pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:145F:01C1.0004    /input/input12
[    2.640248] hid-generic 0003:145F:01C1.0004: input,hidraw3: USB     HID v1.10 Keyboard [MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming Mouse] on     usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0
[    2.642068] input: MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming Mouse as /devices    /pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:145F:01C1.0005    /input/input13
[    2.700575] hid-generic 0003:145F:01C1.0005:     input,hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. Trust Gaming     Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input1
```

I've tried:

- sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf

  - options drm_kms_helper poll=N
- sudo gedit /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/mousepoll  change it to 1 from 0
- sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

  - options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1
- sudo nano /etc/default/grub

  - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"

Comment: Is your mouse's dongle plugged into a USB hub, or some other external device? Try plugging it into a computer's USB port directly. It's partially seen as a keyboard because as a gaming mouse, it has extra keys that emulate keyboard presses. (It looks like some of your fixes have nothing to do with the mouse.)

Comment: I've tried what other people said it worked for them in forums. Some commands have nothing to do, like swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1, but bt_coex_active=0 it's for the interference between bluetooth and wireless. The mouse is connected thru it's stock dongle USB adapter which is connected in laptop's USB port directly.

Comment: To eliminate your account directory, create another user called "Guest" (or whatever), and log out of your normal account, and into the Guest account. See if the problem occurs there.

Comment: I've tried it, but with no result, same stuttering. From time to time I get some crashes, from nautilus or other, latest is this one from 1 min ago:

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/82l3vFc.png)

Comment: I've done something else now, changed in the tlp config: 
sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp

# Set to 0 to disable, 1 to enable USB autosuspend feature.
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0

# Exclude listed devices from USB autosuspend (separate with spaces).
# Use lsusb to get the ids.
USB_BLACKLIST="145f:01c1" 

# Bluetooth devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=1

No stutter until now, I'll see how it will go on and post here the result.

Comment: Yesterday mouse worked fine after the changes, now it have the same stuttering and lag...

Comment: Save your tlp config file, then remove tlp and see what happens.

Comment: No changes, lag comes and goes. Not even the pc heavy used.

Comment: Open a `terminal` window, type `top`, keep the window in view, and note which application/process is at the top when the mouse stutters. Maybe that'll give us a clue.

Comment: screenshot: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/IbODVdf.png)

Comment: gnome-shell shouldn't be that high for any significant length of time. Do you have any GNOME extensions installed? Look at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and turn them ALL off to test. Edit your question with `ls .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`.

Comment: yes, I have extensions installed, gnome-shell isn't that high all the time. That screenshot is when I move the mouse erratically, gnome-shell is getting high %CPU.
    vnm@vnm-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y580:~$ ls .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
    cpupower@mko-sl.de  openweather-extension@jenslody.de  
I deactivated them all from https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ ,but still have the stutter.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I got too annoyed by this and bought a wired mouse, no more stutter. At least I know that it's from the bluetooth or something, I will keep the question open, will test anything else if somebody can still find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command under the sudo:

```
echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

If it helps - the permanent way to apply it is to add the `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` parameter into the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable of `/etc/default/grub` file.